# In C++, will the vector function push_back increase the size of an empty array?

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Quick question. Let's say I declare a vector of size 20. And then I want to add a few integers to it using push_back.

```
vector<int> myVector(20);
myVector.push_back(5);
myVector.push_back(14);
```

Is the capacity of my vector now 22, or is it still 20? Were 5 and 14 added to indices [19] and [20], respectively? Or are they at [0] and [1]?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After those statements its capacity is implementation-defined. (Please note that is different from its size.)

---

```
vector<int> myVector(20);
```

This creates a vector filled with twenty 0's. Its size is twenty, exactly, and its capacity is at least twenty. Whether or not it's exactly twenty is implementation-defined; it may have more (probably not, in practice).

```
myVector.push_back(5);
```

After this, the twenty-first element of the array is 5, and the capacity is once again implementation-defined. (If the capacity had been exactly twenty before, it is now increased in an unspecified manner.)

```
myVector.push_back(14);
```

Likewise, now the twenty-second element of the array is 14, and the capacity is implementation-defined.

---

If you want to reserve space, but not insert elements, you'd do it like this:

```
vector<int> myVector;
myVector.reserve(20); // capacity is at least twenty, guaranteed not
                      // to reallocate until after twenty elements are pushed

myVector.push_back(5); // at index zero, capacity at least twenty.
myVector.push_back(14); // at index one, capacity at least twenty.
```

Comment: Note that C++03 standard 23.2.4/1 requires that `vector`s "support **(amortized) constant time** insert and erase operations at the end", so in practice the capacity usually expands by a factor of two when `push_back()` needs more room.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I didn't know it would fill with 20 0's. That would have really messed my program up. I don't know why I didn't think to just not specify a size, seeing as how they're dynamic and that's what I need. A derp on my behalf.

Answer (score 3):

- `size` is the number of elements in the vector container.
- `capacity` is the size of the allocated storage space
- `push_back` effectively increases the vector size by one, which causes a reallocation of the internal allocated storage if the vector size was equal to the vector capacity before the call.

More info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` increases the size of the `std::vector` and places the new elements at the back of the `vector` (other containers also have a `push_front` method to do the same thing at the front as well).

However, there is a difference between the size and the capacity of a `vector`.  The **size** refers to how many items are actually in the `vector` right now; the **capacity** refers to the total number of items that the `vector` can hold without reallocating memory.  It's possible to `reserve()` memory if you know that you're going to add several elements and don't want to grow the `vector` piecemeal.

Comment: Okay, so push_back doesn't increase the capacity, right? Unless that vector is already at full capacity.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't necessarily increase the capacity.  I only mention it because `std::vector` goes through the trouble of making the distinction so it's important to keep the terms straight, especially when reading documentation for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

As the vector **is not empty** but has a size of 20 (contains 20 elements) and you `push` 2 elements to the `back`, it now contains 22 elements. But the new elements are not placed at indices 19 and 20, but 20 and 21.

If you really want to only reserve enough memory for the vector to hold 20 elements (without actually containing any elements), to prevent costly reallocations, then you should call

```
std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.reserve(20);
```

In this case the vector is still empty, but it has enough memory to add at least 20 elements (using `push_back`, for example) without needing to reallocate its internal storage. In this case the vector only contains the 2 elements you `push`ed`_back`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Essentially what I want to do is create a vector, and only add elements to the end. It didn't occur to me that I don't even have to give a size initially, because vectors are dynamic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `vector` has the member function `push_back`. Other sequences like `deque` have `push_front`.

> 0, 1, 2, ......, final
>
> after addition:
>
> 0, 1, 2, ....., final, addition, ...

You may recall that:

```
capacity() returns the number of elements in the vector sufficient,
without allocating additional memory.
This number can be greater or equal to size.
```

That is, you can not add at front or the middle, since the `vector` is specialized for quick access to elements by index. If you want to add at front and back, you can use `deque` which is similar to `vector`. If you want to add to front, back and anywhere you can use `list`. Note that `list` doesn't provide indexing like `deque` and `vector`.

However, a vector is assumed to have more capacity than its actual size. When you add elements to it, it doesn't necessary allocate additional memory. It does only if the capacity equals the size. On many compilers, the new capacity will be double of the old one. After allocating, it copies all elements in the new location. Such behavior may be expensive in terms of memory, however.

Answer (score 1):

`push_back` will increase the capacity of the vector to at least the new size of the vector, but possibly (i.e. probably) somewhat larger.

Because `push_back` is required to run in O(1) amortized time, each reallocation will be to some multiple of the old capacity.  In a typical implementation that multiple is 2.

But the exact capacity increase is not specified.  If you require precise control over the capacity, use `reserve`.

...

Re-reading your question, I am not sure you understand the difference between a vector's size and its capacity.  The size is the number of elements.  The capacity is the number of elements the vector can hold without performing a reallocation.  That is, you can `push_back` capacity()-size() elements before a reallocation happens.

In your example, 5 and 14 will appear at myVector[20] and myVector[21], respectively.

Comment: Right. What I didn't understand is that vectors dont require a capacity when creating them, that's they're point - they're dynamic, right? So it's kind of pointless to give them an initial capacity.

Comment: @iaacp: No, it's not pointless. If you know in advance how much stuff you plan to put inside the vector, but you don't have the actual stuff on hand when initializing the vector, then you can `reserve()` an amount so that the `vector` will not have to do any reallocation.

Comment: @iiacp:  It is not pointless if you actually care about reallocation.  Reallocation (a) takes time and (b) invalidates references/pointers to elements inside the vector.  `reserve` lets you set the capacity to avoid future reallocations.  Note that your example sets the _size_ of the vector, not the _capacity_.  You are creating a vector of 20 uninitialized integers.